# How to write a pl/sql program to not allow transaction on Sundays using trigger?

Tags: plsql, triggers, plsqldeveloper, datatrigger

I have a table named emp1

```
Create table emp1
(
 Emp_no number(3),
 Name varchar(10),
 Salary number(9,2),
 Dept_no number(3)
);
```

My trigger is

```
create or replace trigger tri1
before insert on emp1
for each row
begin
   if to_char(sysdate,'day')='sunday' then
       dbms_output.put_line('You cannot access');
   End if;
End;
```

After executing this trigger, I insert below statement

```
insert into emp1(Name, Salary, Dept_no) values ('abc',12000,101);
```

Every time I insert its always getting inserted.

I have also tried using exception

```
create or replace trigger tri1 
before insert on emp1 
for each row 
declare
     weekday_error exception;
begin 
if to_char(sysdate,'day')='sunday' then
raise weekday_error;
end if; 
Exception
  when weekday_error then
     dbms_output.put_line('You cannot access');
End;
```

With this method also records are always getting inserted.

```
  create or replace trigger tri1 
    before insert on emp1 
    for each row 

    begin 
    if to_char(sysdate,'Day')='Sunday' then
    raise_application_error(-20000,'Cannot do transaction on Sunday');
    End if; 

End;
```

Comment: that's because the result of `to_char(sysdate,'day')` is **s**unday and not **S**unday. To get Sunday you shoud write Day instead of day

Comment: I changed it to Day and Sunday also but still its not working. Trigger is getting created but then when i inserted records are getting inserted

Comment: @jaicy - Did you test the 2nd trigger in your question on sunday ? :) i don't see anything wrong with it. it should work.

Comment: Yes... I tried that also. But everytime its getting inserted nd not showing 'you cannot access'

Comment: Am i inserting it in a wrong way? After creating the trigger i am directly trying to insert it.

Comment: @JaicyJoseph - Have a look at my answer, I did test it and it works fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is just one tiny problem with your trigger. TO_CHAR(sysdate,'day') actually returns 9 characters.

like *MONDAY* that is 6 characters and then 3 Space characters. This is because of *WEDNESDAY* which has 9 characters.

Your trigger just needs the trim function

```
create trigger trig1 before insert on emp1
for each row
begin
    if trim(to_char(sysdate, 'day')) = 'sunday' then
        raise_application_error(-20000,'ikidyounot, today was - ' || to_char(sysdate, 'day'));
    end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: Oh ok... Thanks a lot. Thanks for taking your precious time for answering. I will try this and tell You soon

Comment: @JaicyJoseph - Do mark the question answered, if it helped you after your testing :)

Comment: Wow.. superb... Thank u so much sir for helping me. It worked